# Creating error macro

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that will deliver a pop up in the event that a field is left blank. The problem that I have is, once you acknowledge the error, it goes away and lets you proceed without filling in the field. Does anyone know what I am missing in the macro? I won't post the entire script because it is very long but it currently looks like this...

```
If Range("L58") = "Sigma Network" And Range("M58") = "" Then MsgBox "Please enter cable length "
```

Can I create one script that will work for all of the others or does each need to have its own?

Comment: *Does anyone know what I am missing in the macro? I won't post the entire script because it is very long...*  **<<** These two statements seem to be at odds with one another. Nobody here can read your mind...

Comment: Instead of `MsgBox` you probably want to use `InputBox` and assign the return value to `Range("M58")`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It is the exact same script but different cells. So L55, L56, L57 etc. I didn't think it would be necessary to see 50 of the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: Are you familiar with `For...Next` loop statement? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601.aspx

Comment: No, I am very new to vba (self taught) and thankful for all of the forums because I would be lost with most of this and the help of everyone!

Comment: I will look into the loop statement. Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing basically the same operation 50 times, it's probably better suited to use a loop structure with some variables.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, something like:

```
If Range("L58") = "Sigma Network" And Range("M58") = "" Then 
    Range("M58").Value = InputBox("Please enter cable length ", "Input value!", 0)
End If
```

You would of course need additional logic to prevent the user from entering a 0-value or empty string, etc.,

If you're doing this on for example, 50 different pairs of cells, (say L58 to L107 and M58 to M107 for example) this is a basic loop structure that you could use:

```
Dim cl as Range
For Each cl in Range("L58:L107")
    If cl.Value = "Sigma Network" and cl.Offset(0,1).Value = "" Then
        cl.Offset(0,1).Value = GetValue("Please enter cable length ", "Input value!", 0)
    End If
Next
```

The loop can be further refined (e.g., if "Sigma Network" isn't the only thing you're checking for, or if you need different message text for the input box based on some other conditions, etc.

This will require the custom `GetValue` function which invokes the `InputBox` prompt, and configured to prevent 0-value input from the user. Additional logic may be required to prevent other types of data entry.

```
Function GetValue(msg as String, _
                  Optional title as String = "", _
                  Optional default as Double = 0)
'Function that calls the InputBox method
    Dim ret
    Do Until ret <> 0
        ret = InputBox(msg, title, default)
    Loop
    GetValue = ret
End Function
```